# Automatically instantiate singleton at launch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, singleton

I have a singleton `Session` that I want instantiated at application launch. How do I do that?

I'm using this method of creating the singleton: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html

Comment: Your `Session` singleton sounds like (given its name) something that aught not be a singleton. Rather, 'session' objects typically are per client, and not global.

Comment: I thought so too. But according to that page, any object that is not owned by any other object, is not a constant and exists alone should be a singleton. My `Session` singleton conforms to all three conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first line of your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
 [YourSingletonClass class]; // ADD THIS LINE
```

it will trigger `initialize` method initialization in your singleton class

```
+ (void) initialize {
     _innerInstance = [[YourSingletonClass alloc] init];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you access the singleton in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method, they will should get set up.